# Drop Down Menu Help needed

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu

I am creating our menu, for site we are working on. I just dont get drop down menus.

I am trying to create 2 versions, for us to choose from.. on click and drop down, or on hover and drop down.

Here is a fiddle I have made,

http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/S4kYN/

The code within the fiddle, isnt our fully working code, as I have stripped out as much of the garbage from the css, to fire up the fiddle.

I was reading on various sites, that we need to investigate ul li li styling... and really got wrapped up in confusion.
By just looking at our code, could someone please give me some pointers please.

I am not looking for anyone to wholly code this, just to assist in where we need to go.. Ideally I prefer to accomplish this without the use of js.

Answer (score 0):

is what you mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/yuliantoadi/hMr7h/